# How to drop/extract elements of a list which starts with Plus

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have the following list :

```
list={a^2, b^2, a^-1, a^2+b^2, (a+b+c)^-1, (a+b-c)^-2}
Do[Print[list[[i]]//FullForm],{i,1,Length[list]}]
```

I want to break this list into two lists: one containing elements starting with `Power` and another starting with `Plus`. In this case it will be

```
list1 = {a^2, b^2, a^-1, (a+b+c)^-1, (a+b-c)^-2}
list2 = {a^2+b^2}
```

A priori the position of elements starting with `Power` or `Plus` is not fixed and also the elements could be complicated. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Try: Cases[list, HoldPattern[Power[__]]] and
Cases[list, HoldPattern[Plus[__]]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grouped = GroupBy[list, Head]
```

> ```
> <|Power -> {a^2, b^2, 1/a, 1/(a + b + c), 1/(a + b - c)^2}, 
>  Plus -> {a^2 + b^2}|>
> ```

```
grouped  /@ {Power, Plus}
```

> ```
> {{a^2, b^2, 1/a, 1/(a + b + c), 1/(a + b - c)^2}, 
>  {a^2 + b^2}}
> ```

```
Lookup[{Plus, Power}] @ grouped
```

> ```
> {{a^2 + b^2}, 
>  {a^2, b^2, 1/a, 1/(a + b + c), 1/(a + b - c)^2}}
> ```

```
KeyTake[Plus] @ grouped
```

> ```
> <|Plus -> {a^2 + b^2}|>
> ```

```
KeyDrop[Plus] @ grouped
```

> ```
> <|Power -> {a^2, b^2, 1/a, 1/(a + b + c), 1/(a + b - c)^2}|>
> ```

Answer (score 6):

```
list = {a^2, b^2, a^-1, a^2+b^2, (a+b+c)^-1, (a+b-c)^-2};

{list1, list2} = GatherBy[list, Head]

(* Out:

{
 {a^2, b^2, a^(-1), (a + b + c)^(-1), (a + b - c)^(-2)}, 
 {a^2 + b^2}
}

*)
```

---

If you want to specify in which order the heads should be extracted, then you could use multiple Cases statements:

```
{powerList, plusList} = Cases[list, Blank[#]]& /@ {Power, Plus}

(* Out: 
{
 {a^2, b^2, 1/a, 1/(a + b + c), 1/(a + b - c)^2},
 {a^2 + b^2}}
}
*)
```

Comment: Nice solution, except you don't know in advance which head will be the first in the pair

Comment: @RomaLee Good point, although I am not sure that it matters to OP, but it can be easily and automatically addressed. See edit.

Comment: I always suffer from the absence of TakeDrop analog of Cases/DeleteCases and the necessity to call Cases twice. But because of arbitrary order in Gather, it is almost unavoidable. Another way is to add dummy element with head Plus to the beginning, but then you have to delete it. Not nice either.

Comment: @RomaLee That's why `GroupBy` is almost always preferable to `GatherBy`.

Answer (score 3):

```
{l1, l2} = Function[x, Select[#, #[[0]] === x &]]&[list]/@{Power, Plus}
```

Alternatively, using `Pick`:

```
{lone,ltwo} = Pick[#1, #1[[All,0]], #2]&[list,#]&/@{Power, Plus}
```

```
l1
l2
```

$$
   \left\{a^2,b^2,\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{a+b+c},\frac{1}{(a+b-c)^2}\right\}
$$

$$
\left\{a^2+b^2\right\}
$$

Comment: In addition, `{L1,L2}=Select[list, OperatorApplied[#2[[0]] === # &,2][#]]&/@{Power, Plus}`

Answer (score 2):

Cases do the job.

```
{a^2, b^2, a^-1, a^2 + b^2, (a + b + c)^-1, (a + b - c)^-2} // {Cases[_Power]@#, Cases[_Plus]@#} &
```